# Long duration on Jenkins skipped tests

Tags: junit, jenkins

I am using Jenkins ver. 1.408 to run tests.

I have notice the timing in the result is incorrect. If I run a test plan with all skipped test in the Jenkins result I will see that the duration of the @ignored tests was a few minutes.

For example I ran this 3 tests, 2 are marked as ignored and in the results it seem to take 3:30 minutes, 1:10 for every test (including the skipped ones)

```
test1   1 min 10 sec    Skipped
test2   1 min 10 sec    Passed
test3   1 min 10 sec    Skipped
```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are those classes or methods? And if they are methods are they in the same class?

Comment: this are 3 methods marked as @Test in the same class.
It takes the time of the Passed test and put it on the Skipped ones.
So the run time of the class is 3:30 minutes.

Comment: Do you have anything that is executed before the actual test method? I think `@Before` shouldn't run but e.g. `@BeforeClass` or setting up the application context with `@RunWith`. Although they only should run once before the first test. But it should give you a hint on what to look for.

Comment: I have a @RunWith but it is not what causing this issue. 
The real run time is 1:10 the time of the single test, but in the report it show the 3:30 so I cannot relay on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug.
I have seen similar incorrect durations in different places in jenkins test results views. But it is not really a problem for us.

It could be related to this issue?

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42438

Wrong JUnit test duration shown in classes list

Resolved May 2019 and reported as fixed in jUnit plugin 1.27